# why is a dict size 72 bytes after calling .clear() compared to 240 bytes when instantiating one?

Tags: python

What is happening under the hood to have a dict size of 72 bytes (according to getsizeof(dict) after calling .clear() on the dictionary, when a freshly instantiated one returns 240 bytes?

I know a simple dict has a starting size of '8' and resizes itself upon ~66% fullness, is this relatable to the size after calling clear?

I am studying dictionaries and found this quite interesting, what is actually happening?

```py
>>> from sys import getsizeof
>>> dict = {}
>>> getsizeof(dict)
240
>>> dict.clear()
>>> getsizeof(dict)
72
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we are talking CPython, your intuition is correct. When creating a new dictionary, a keyspace [is allocated](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/da63b321f63b697f75e7ab2f88f55d907f56c187/Objects/dictobject.c#L3273) in `dict_new` of size [PyDict_MINSIZE](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/da63b321f63b697f75e7ab2f88f55d907f56c187/Objects/dictobject.c#L104). This consumes memory. When calling `.clear()`, the keyspace [is re-wired](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/da63b321f63b697f75e7ab2f88f55d907f56c187/Objects/dictobject.c#L1709) to a statically allocated empty key-space, making the dictionary truly empty.